# Some haskell dynamic library missing

Tags: haskell

This error message failing my installation of `haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1`

`ld: library not found for -lHScpphs-1.18.5-ghc7.8.2`

So I guess my cpphs is missing. When I tried to install cpphs, however

```
$ cabal install cpphs
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
cpphs-1.18.5
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

The similar error happens for `text-1.1.1.3`.

I have tried erasing everything and reinstalling `haskell-platform` but it doesnt work.

I use `haskell-platform` installed from `homebrew`, but I had already had the latest version of `cabal` and `ghc`

```
λ ~/cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.1 of the Cabal library
λ ~/ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.2
```

`find` ing the `*.dylib` gives no result.

Comment: So I suppose that indeed `libHScpphs-1.18.5-ghc7.8.2` is not on your system? Perhaps a naming or path problem?

Comment: yes, it is not on my system. (added to question)

Comment: update: I wiped haskell-platform and build ghc, Cabal, cabal-install from source and everything works like a charm.

Comment: @evanbas you might like [cabal sandboxes](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html)